# Import content of a text field from a HTML page into an excel

Tags: html, excel, populate

I am trying to create a feature which allows a user to upload a txt file or the content of a file from a HTML web page and populate an Excel sheet (Excel template).

My Excel will have some rules in order to assess data populated.

I do not know how to create this bridge and which language is needed? I was thinking of PHP (as there should be some APIs). What about JS?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library such as SheetsJS to do this. You can both parse and write to Excel with this. You would need to have properly formatted data to pass to it though.

https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Comment: Hi PJ, Thank you for that. Did you have a kind of tuto to make it work?

Comment: There's quite a lot of demos and full documentation on GitHub. I think this demo relates closely to what you're trying to do: http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/ I will caveat this in saying that you will need a fair knowledge of JS for this kind of project!